# Loader.io test "Maintain client load"

Tags: php, apache, testing, nginx, lamp

I just wonder how "Maintain client load" test' work and how to properly configure our environment (LAMP + nginX) to get the best result ? Can anyone explain me this test?

Answer (score 2):

loader.io engineer here. I fully expect this question to be closed by noon, but I'll take a stab at explaining it anyway.

"maintain load" tests are kind of a strange beast. It may help to think of any loader test in terms of a "workload", which consists of the list of URLs you are testing.

In loader, you specify a number of clients for your test, and each client takes a copy of the workload and runs it. If the client is in "maintain load" mode, it iterates over the URLs in the workload repeatedly - maintaining its load. All the other clients do the same.

Below is a visualization of what the pattern of requests looks like, taken from a [loader.io blog post](https://loader.io/blog/2014/07/16/understanding-different-test-types/)

[image: Pattern of maintain client load requests]

This has some interesting side-effects. If you configure your test to ramp up the number of clients, what we see quite often is that response times at the beginning of a test are low, so clients are iterating fast over their workload. As more clients are added, responses get slower, effectively slowing down the request rate. This can make maintain load tests difficult to reason about, and that's why I personally don't recommend starting with maintain load tests.

As far as configuring your stack for best results, it depends on what "best results" means for you and what you are even doing with your stack. There is no silver bullet. If you're serving a static website then cache the heck out of it for best performance. If you have a complex app making database queries on every request and rendering things - profile your code, db queries, and everything else to tune your performance.

Define some requirements and set some performance goals - e.g. do you expect to a hundred page views within an hour? A minute? Figure out what those requirements are and *then* go ahead and test it.

Once you have your requirements, you can use loader.io and/or other load testing tools in a much more meaningful way. If your current performance doesn't match your requirements and goals, you can use these tools to check your progress. Start with small tests that your servers handle easily and increase it until things break. Then optimize your code/database queries/etc and test again to see how much you've improved.

Comment: Nice post, and thanks for disclosing your affiliation.